# Rpm Installation Error, libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6

Tags: linux, command-line, 64-bit, redhat, rpm

Im trying to install this rpm "libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64"

But Im having this error:-

```
# rpm -ivh libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1d1e034b: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64) is already installed
        file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 from install of libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
```

Im also trying to install this rpm "libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64" as my previous attempt to install "libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64", but the method does not working.

I did try replace "rpm -ivh --replacefiles"  command., in order to replace libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 with libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64, as well with libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64 but the method is also does not working.

I also did try the sudo command, but still getting the similar situation. Any suggestions would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its alrite, I have got it figure out..
Just force installation the rpm using this command

rpm -ivh --old-package

rpm -ivh --force

Either should do.

Comment: The second is a really, *really* bad idea unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. It can very easily silently break things. You installed version 4.4.4 over 4.4.7. `--force` can break dependencies, etc.

Comment: Well, lets hope that did't happen then. If something happen then Ill ask in this forum. No problem